# I found an error in the compilation of GNAT in the Command Line

Tags: ada, gnat

source code

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
procedure hello_world is
begin
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_line(“Hello World”);
    Ada.Text_IO.Put(“by Jeffy Fifa”);
    Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
end hello_world;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0tFM.png)

Comment: Please post text, not images. And, maybe the problem is that you haven’t installed GNAT?

Comment: You probably need to add `gnatmake` to your `PATH`; also, the "switch character cannot be followed by a blank."

Answer (score 3):

Well, as Simon Wright already stated in a comment, ensure that GNAT is installed correctly. You can download the community edition [here](https://www.adacore.com/download). Then, after the installation succeeded:

- Ensure that `C:\GNAT\2018\bin` is in the search path:

```
C:\> echo %PATH%
[...];C:\GNAT\2018\bin;[...]
```

- Ensure that `gnatmake` executes:

```
C:\> gnatmake --version
GNATMAKE Community 2018 (20180523-73)
Copyright (C) 1995-2018, Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

- Switch to the folder where the file `hello_world.adb` is located, and try to compile the file using:

```
E:\> gnatmake -g hello_world.adb
gcc -c -g hello_world.adb
gnatbind -x hello_world.ali
gnatlink hello_world.ali -g
```

Comment: I tried to compile it saying                                                                        `E:\GNAT\Code file>gnatmake -g hello_world.adb
gcc -c -g hello_world.adb
hello_world.adb:4:30: illegal character
hello_world.adb:5:25: illegal character
gnatmake: "hello_world.adb" compilation error`

Comment: Can you edit your original question and add the source code of `hello_world.adb`?

Comment: @jeffy Fifa - Good to hear! It seems that you used the left/right double quotation marks (```“``` and ```”```; ```U+201C``` and ```U+201D```) instead of the standard quotation mark (```"```; ```U+0022```). The difference is subtle. Indeed, Ada requires strings to be bracketed by plain quotation characters as in ```"Hello World"``` (see also RM [2.6](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-2-6.html)).

Comment: It work !!! but I have a new problem when running the command `./hello_world.exe` It shows up as`'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` @DeeDee

Comment: I must apologize if I have more questions. @DeeDee

Comment: Well, make sure that `hello_world.exe` is there (check with `dir`) and try without the `./` prefix. So use `hello_world.exe` or just `hello_world` (without the extention). The `./` prefix is typically used on Linux, not on Windows

Comment: You use `./hello_world` on Unix-based systems, because the current directory (`.`) is (usually) not on the PATH. On Windows, that would be `.\hello_world`, because the directory (folder) separator is \ not /; but you probably don’t need to include it at all, because the current directory _is_ on the PATH.